# Writing an AJAX POST request to be recieved by a Django view

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm trying to write an AJAX post function to be recieved by one of my django views, however it isn't working.

Here is my ajax call

```
                $.ajax({

                    url : 'localhost:8000/increment?amount=5&persist=yes',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {
                        'amount' : amount
                    },
                    dataType:'json',
                    success : function(data) {              
                    alert('Data: '+data);
                    },
                    error : function(request,error)
                    {

                    }
                });
```

and here is the django view that is supposed to be recieving it

```
@login_required
def Increment(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        amount = request.GET.get('amount', 0) # returns 5
        persist = request.GET.get('persist', 'no') #returns yes
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    profile.coins += amount
    profile.save(update_fields=['coins'])
    return HttpResponse('') #return void
```